# How to extract paths (pdb file) that are stored in an exe?

Tags: windows, path, exe

When an executable is built, it stores the path of the pdb files it generates. How can I find what this path is given I have the executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is the link utility. It is available when you run developer command prompt for VS2015.

```
c:\>link -dump -headers c:\path\app.exe
```

The pdb files path is in the debug directories section.

It is worth nothing that this tool is available only from visual studio command line as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx5b050y.aspx).

> You can start this tool only from the Visual Studio command prompt.
>   You cannot start it from a system command prompt or from File
>   Explorer.

Comment: Add [/DEBUG] option into Visual Studio Link Command Options. A PDB file will be generated.